# Stream loadbalancing

Tags: apache-flink

I have two streams. One is an event stream, the other is a database update stream. I want to enrich the event stream with information built from the DB update stream.

The event stream is very voluminous and is partitioned using 5 fields. This gives me good distribution. The DB stream is a lot less chattier, and is partitioned using two fields. I am currently connecting the two streams using the two common fields and using a flapMap to enrich the first stream. The flatMap operator uses ValueState to maintain state, which is automatically keyed by the two common fields.

I find that the load in the event stream tends to be skewed in terms of the two common fields. This causes uneven loadbalancing across the flapMap instances and a few instances are around 10 times more loaded than the others.

I am thinking a better approach would be to broadcast the DB update stream across all flatMap instances and simply forward the event stream based on its existing partitioning scheme. However the issue is that because there are no keys specified for the connect operator, I cannot use ValueState.

Other than implementing custom logic to manually extract the key and update maintain state, is there any anything else I can do?

Is there a simpler approach I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `Checkpointed` interface with the `CoFlatMapFunction` to checkpoint the broadcasted DB updates instead of using the key-value state interface.